# JLabel overwrites JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing

When the `aboutWindow` frame is opened, there is only the label(-contents) `name` visible, the menu bar is missing. When the label is commented out, the bar appears, but it fills out the entire frame. What am i missing?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main
{

    public static JDialog aboutWindow;

    public static void about () {
    //JDialog aboutWindow = new JDialog();
    Main.aboutWindow = new JDialog();
    Main.aboutWindow.setTitle("About kingfisher a0.0.3");
    Main.aboutWindow.setSize(300,600);
    Main.aboutWindow.setModal(true);
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
                JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("quit");
                    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListene121r() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                            Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                control.add(quit);
            menubar.add(control);
        Main.aboutWindow.add(menubar);
    JLabel name = new JLabel("kingfisher");
    Main.aboutWindow.add(name);
    Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
    }


    public static void main (String args[]){
    //Defined window dimensions
    JFrame controlpanel = new JFrame();
    controlpanel.setTitle("kingfisher Control Panel");
    controlpanel.setSize(500,400);
    controlpanel.add(new JLabel("The angels have the blue box"));
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        //defining menu groups
            JMenu windows = new JMenu("Windows");
                JCheckBoxMenuItem chat = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Chat");
                JCheckBoxMenuItem filetransfer = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Filetransfer");
                JCheckBoxMenuItem settings = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Settings");
                windows.add(chat);
                windows.add(filetransfer);
                windows.add(settings);
            JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
                JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Quit");
                quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                );
                control.add(quit);
            JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
                JMenuItem support = new JMenuItem("Support");
                JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
                    about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                            Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(true);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                help.add(support);
                help.add(about);
            menubar.add(control);
            menubar.add(windows);
            menubar.add(help);
        controlpanel.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    controlpanel.setVisible(true);
    };
};
```

Comment: Running that code (after changing `new ActionListene121r` to `new ActionListener`) produces a `NullPointerException` here..

Comment: oops, those typos were not intended. but the `NullPointerExeption`, i cannot see. which LOC does the error refer to?

Comment: that's an interesting style of formatting, to say the least... your tabs are all over the shop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the JMenuBar, use [JDialog.setJMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar))

```
Main.aboutWindow = new JDialog();
    Main.aboutWindow.setTitle("About kingfisher a0.0.3");
    Main.aboutWindow.setSize(300,600);
    Main.aboutWindow.setModal(true);
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu control = new JMenu("Control");
                JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("quit");
                    quit.addActionListener(new ActionListene121r() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                            Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                control.add(quit);
            menubar.add(control);

        Main.aboutWindow.setJMenuBar(menubar); //changed

    JLabel name = new JLabel("kingfisher");
    Main.aboutWindow.add(name);
    Main.aboutWindow.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `JDialog` uses a `BorderLayout` layout by default, when you add components to this kind of layout without specifying the position, they are added in the center (replacing the previous component added in the center).

Your `JLabel` is replacing the `JMenuBar` because it is added afterwards.

You can do something like this:

```
Main.aboutWindow.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Or as @ControlAltDel has mentioned use the default way of adding a menu bar to a dialog:

```
Main.aboutWindow.setJMenuBar(menubar);
```

Comment: could you give me an example position specification?

Comment: You can find details about the `BorderLayout` layout [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)